# Remove specific character from string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable which is a VARCHAR and will contain a list of folders (1 or more).
It may looks like that :

```
@Folder = '/folder1/folder2/'
or
@Folder = 'folder1/folder2/'
or
@Folder = '/Folder1/Folder2'
```

And if the first and the last characater of my string are '/', i want to remove them and my variable should be always

```
@Folder = 'Folder1/Folder2'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions to do this.

```
DECLARE @Folder varchar(20) = '/folder1/folder2/';

IF LEFT(@folder,1) = '/' 
SET @Folder = RIGHT(@Folder ,LEN(@Folder)-1);

IF RIGHT(@folder,1) = '/' 
SET @Folder = LEFT(@Folder ,LEN(@Folder)-1);

SELECT @Folder;
```

**Result**

```
(No column name)
folder1/folder2
```